# How to show/hide Activity views from a ListFragment

Tags: android, listactivity

I have the classic `ListActivity` - `ListFragment` design with the `ListFragment` fetching data via a cursor Loader.

There are 2 possible outcomes in the basic arrangement -

the cursor is either empty or has data.

With data the `list_row.xml` is populated with items from the database.

If empty, I get a blank screen with no information for the user.

I have setup a `TextView <i>"No records found message"</i>` that can be be made Visible or Invisible from the ListFragment. The problem is:

1. ListFragment cannot access Views on the ListActivity.
2. How do I call the following ListActivity method from the ListFragment?

```
    public void updateView(boolean data) {

        if (data) {         
             noRecordsFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);       
        } else {            
             noRecordsFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

I have tried to access from the `onLoadFinished` of the `ListFragment`, but this is not accessble. Any help?

Comment: I don't really understand your first issue, since the view should be part of your fragment's layout, not the activity's, right? With respect to toggling the 'empty' message: why don't you simply use the built-in  `setEmptyView(...)` of `ListView` or `setEmptyText(...)` of the `ListFragment` functionality? The first allows you to display a more complex view hierarchy for the empty message, in case you need to.

Comment: Thanks a million! This has turned out a lot simpler than I thought. I have used the `setEmptyText(...)` of the `ListFragment` and it works fine!

Comment: Glad to hear. I've also added the comment as answer, so you can accept it and help other people who may bump into this thread because of a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to MH for the alternative approach, but I have bumped onto an answer to my own question. While I think MH's answer is the most suitable for my case, I include a solution to what I originally wanted to do just in case someone needs to use it for things other than listviews.

Well, I included the `if (cursor.getCount() < 1)` block inside the `onLoadFinished()` of the Cursor Loader, kike so:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

    if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {

        TextView noNotes    = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.noNotes);
        noNotes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per earlier comment:

I don't really understand your first issue, since the view should be part of your fragment's layout, not the activity's, right?

With respect to toggling the 'empty' message: why don't you simply use the built-in functionality of [`setEmptyView(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) of `ListView` or [`setEmptyText(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html#setEmptyText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) of `ListFragment` (also available in the support libary)? The first allows you to display a more complex view hierarchy for the empty message, in case you need to

Comment: What I meant in the first part of the question is that I could not call a method declared on the `ListActivity class` from the `ListFragment class`. E.g. calling thus `getActivity().callMethod(params)` gives an error.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. In order for that to work you would have to cast the result of `getActivity()` to your specific implementation, e.g.: `((MyActivity)getActivity).callMethod(params)`. A better, more generic approach, however, is to work with listener interfaces and have the activity register as a listener to the fragment.